# MySQL-python 1.2.3 and OS X 10.5: 64- or 32-bit?

Tags: mysql, macos, 32bit-64bit, mysql-python

I've been happily using Django and MySQL in development on an existing machine running OS X 10.4 Tiger, and have set up a similar environment in 10.5 Leopard on a new 64-bit MacBook, with a working MySQL and Python 2.6.4.

However, now I want them to communicate, `easy_install MySQL-python` gave `ld warning`s that the `file is not of the required architecture`, which led me to test my Python 2.4.6 install (from the [Mac OS X disc image](http://www.python.org/download/)):

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.maxint
2147483647
```

Ah. So my Python install appears to be 32-bit and (I think?) won't install MySQL-python for my 64-bit MySQL. There are lots of hacks out there for MySQL-python on OS X (mostly 1.2.2), but - after hours of reading - I'm pretty sure they won't fix this architecture mismatch. So I'm stuck because I can't decide whether to:

- give up, remove the [64-bit MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.5.html#macosx-dmg) install (thorough methods, please?) and use the 32-bit MySQL disc image instead;
- re-install Python in 64-bit mode from the tarball,
  `--with-universal archs-64-bit` and `--enable-universalsdk=`
  as [detailed in Python.org's 2.6 news](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6/NEWS.txt).

So my questions for anyone who has encountered this issue are:

1. Is installing 64-bit Python on OS X 10.5 worth bothering with?
2. If so, (naive, lazy question!) how are the two required arguments combined?
3. If I just skip along in 32-bit (as on my working setup) what am I missing?

I'm after a hassle-free install that's easy to reproduce on other machines (possible student use) so I'd really welcome your opinions, please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm posting this here in case anyone finds this page and needs an answer...

Solution: [remove](http://akrabat.com/computing/uninstalling-mysql-on-mac-os-x-leopard/) [the MySQL](http://obscuredclarity.blogspot.com/2009/08/uninstall-mysql-on-mac-os-x.html) 64-bit install (change the below to match your MySQL version number):

```
cd /usr/local
sudo rm -rf mysql-5.1.41-osx10.5-x86_64
rm -r mysql
cd /Library/Receipts/
rm -r mysql-5.1.41-osx10.5-x86_64.pkg
```

Install the latest 32-bit MySQL package from the [downloads page](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) and [set it up as required](http://hivelogic.com/articles/installing-mysql-on-mac-os-x/).

Remove MySQL-python with:

```
easy_install -m MySQL-python
```

Then delete the egg in `site-packages` and make sure `easy_install -m` removed the package line in the `easy-install.pth` file there.

Start up MySQL, then re-install MySQL-python (make sure you get the latest version - 1.2.3 - at time of writing): `easy_install MySQL-python`

Test it:

```
>>> import MySQLdb
```

For me, that solved the problem. No need to edit _mysql.c ([as advised](http://www.mangoorange.com/2008/08/01/installing-python-mysqldb-122-on-mac-os-x/) for [MySQL-python 1.2.2](http://davidmichaelthompson.com/2008/02/18/notes-installing-django-python-mysql-on-os-x/)) or mess with any other settings.

Should you need them (if the above fails, or if you really want to try a 64-bit install), here are some of the links used while researching this:

- [Andy Dustman, MySQLdb developer](http://mysql-python.blogspot.com/2008/03/i-am-not-dead.html)
- [Django on Leopard](http://yousefourabi.com/blog/2008/06/django-on-leopard/)
- [Jim B's Blog: installing fresh version of python 2.6.4](http://blog.jbglenn.net/2009/12/installing-fresh-version-of-python-264.html)
- [Search results for setuptools ARCHFLAGS 32 bit - MarkMail](http://markmail.org/message/5znj3cytg4x6hiul)
- [MySQL-Python and Apple OSX 10.5 (Leopard)](http://www.keningle.com/?p=11)
- [Installing Django / Python / Mysql on OS X | DavidMichaelThompson](http://davidmichaelthompson.com/2008/02/18/notes-installing-django-python-mysql-on-os-x/)

But [note this](http://tickletik.blogspot.com/2008/12/python-and-mysql-on-64bit.html):

> "if you go 64, then you will have to
>   recompile every single thing that
>   interacts with python, mysql and
>   apache to work as a 64 bit arch
>   program"

And for anyone on Snow Leopard:

- [mysql-python and Snow Leopard](http://cd34.com/blog/programming/python/mysql-python-and-snow-leopard/)
- [Python-MySQL for Snow Leopard](http://birdhouse.org/blog/2009/02/21/python-mysql-connections-on-mac-os/)

Finally, the [MacPython 2.7 installer](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/) now covers 64 bit. See this post for the [differences between running 64 and/or 32 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588472/32-bit-operation-vs-64-bit-operation-on-a-64bit-machine-os).

Answer (score 1):

I found the following steps (with Snow Leopard) got me 64 bit MySQL and 64 bit Python (on an early 2011 Macbook Pro)

1. Install Xcode
2. Install 64 bit MySQL
3. Install latest python
4. Install easy_install

   Download and install appropriate egg from: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools and then run the shell script (in my case …)

   sudo sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg
5. Install the MySQLdb python library

   export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin/

   sudo easy_install MySQL-python
6. Change ~/.profile to include the following lines:

   export VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=no

   export VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_64_BIT=yes
7. Make the libmysqlclient.18.dylib available

   sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib

Comment: Thanks Bryan - useful. Python 2.7 has a 64 bit installer http://www.python.org/getit/ so when I eventually go to Snow Leopard, I'll probably start with that :-)